# 2009 Jeep Liberty Engine

Tags: engine, jeep, liberty, part-interchange

My 2009 Jeep Liberty’s engine seized and I’m looking for a new motor. Found two for the same price, however one is for a 2008 liberty and the other is for a 2009 liberty. Is there any differences between the engine for a 2008 liberty and a 2009 liberty? I’m only asking because the one for the 2008 liberty has less miles so if I can go with that one I will.

Comment: What does your workshop manual say? Also, that will have alm the info like torque settings you will need.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! There seems to be a break between 2008 and 2009 depending on what options came on your vehicle. I cannot pinpoint exactly what the differences might be, but if I were you, I'd assume there's a difference and go with the 2009. Mopar is offering three different short blocks. One which breaks before 2008; one which breaks for 2009 and later; and a third one which goes from 2004 to 2012.